# Fabric crashlytics reports crashes in obfuscated format

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I use crashlytics to send my reports but crashs not de-obfuscated like this:

```
Fatal Exception: c.a
```

I readed [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html) and added

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

to my proguard-rules file and there is no

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

in my configuration files. this is my build.gradle buildTypes part:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            
        }
        debug_server {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true

            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            minifyEnabled false

        }

}
```

not all of my crashes are like this and I updated crashlytics to 2.9.4 version.

**UPDATE:**

I just skipped this

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

as I don't need to skip running proguard on Crashlytics.

**UPDATE2:** v2.9.9 of crashlytics. Not fixed until now. I can't detect the real cause of bugs.

Comment: Hey, Paul from Fabric here. I'd recommend you reach out to us at support(at)fabric(dot)io with your package name, organization name, and a link to the obfuscated crashes in your dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: @buser problem still there. I specially see this problem with kotlin code.

Comment: Hi @David, Any progress with this problem

Comment: @buser Problem is not fixed. "Caused by c.c" I can't get rid of this.

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin No not fixed until now.

Comment: Is this problem still occurred right now? I use Android with Kotlin still see that problem. Please help.

Comment: @Darari I fixed my problem with accepted answer.

Comment: @David I still got an issue. I've tried accepted answer to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add an extra rule to *proguard* file to keep all *Kotlin* exceptions

`-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception`

Comment: Yes, That's correct. I assumed than Custom Exception means that Exceptions I wrote By myself in app but library exceptions like KotlinNullPointerException is need this rule to not been obfuscated. Thanks.

Comment: I have -keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception in proguard rules. But some of crashes still obfuscated. Why?

Comment: @Mahdi it may be because Java vs Kotlin? Not sure.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the problem.

Have you tried adding `firebase-crash`?

build.gradle(app level) in `dependencies`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'

android{
   ...
}
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
```

build.gradle(Proejct level)

```
    buildscript {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
        // ...
      }

      dependencies {
        // ...
        // For Android Studio 2.x, use firebase-plugins version 1.1.1
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
        // For Android Studio 3.0, use firebase-plugins version 1.1.5
        //classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
      }
    }
```

Try this and, if it doesn't solve your problem, let me know.

Plus, using `-keep` is not recommended.

Alternatively, you can check `ANR & Crash` on `Google Play Console`

Go to your app, and open `Android vitals` > `ANR & Crash`

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android

Comment: Firebase Crash Reporting already discontinued, it is recommended to use Firebase Crashlytics directly @c-an